# Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Выдает такую ошибку

```
 Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
 syntax to use near 'order = '3', img = 'apple.png' WHERE id = '1'' at line 1
```

сам код выглядит так:

```
function updateGoods() {
    $conn  = connect();
    $id    = $_POST['id'];
    $name  = $_POST['gname'];
    $cost  = $_POST['gcost'];
    $descr = $_POST['gdescr'];
    $order = $_POST['gorder'];
    $img   = $_POST['gimg'];

    $sql = "UPDATE goods SET name = '$name', cost = '$cost', description = '$descr', order = '$order', img = '$img' WHERE id = '$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
        echo "1";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Почему происходит эта ошибка?

Comment: ORDER - зарезервированное слово. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html Переименуйте поле.

Comment: либо используйте в обратных кавычках `\`order\``, но лучше переименовать в какой нить `ord` и не париться.

Comment: сработало, спасибо большое!

Comment: А как же классический совет? *Не стройте строку запроса таким образом*?